# MsgBox () - why does it work with one parameter but not with multiple parameters?

Tags: vba

This is a very theoretical question that I would like to learn about for expanding my understanding of the VBA language, but did not find anything in the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx) nor on previous questions here and other forums (maybe it's just not worthy wondering why?).

If I write:

```
MsgBox "myPrompt", vbYesNo, "MyTitle"
```

it's coming out a message box with custom prompt, button and title. 
However, if I write this I get a compile error (Expected "="):

```
MsgBox ("myPrompt", vbYesNo, "MyTitle")
```

Until now, it's all about syntax. In the second case I am supposed to store the return value of the function into a variable, so I pretty much agree on the fact the "=" sign is expected. However, the following line will work:

```
MsgBox("myPrompt")
```

and it is anyway returning the value `1`, which I can see by simply running

```
a = MsgBox("myPrompt")
MsgBox a
```

So, the reason why `MsgBox ("myPrompt", vbYesNo, "MyTitle")` doesn't work without assignment does not seem anymore, according to me, supposed to be related to the fact that a variable assignment is expected as the compile error is saying. 
Could anyone kindly explain this to me, please?

Comment: Parantheses indicate to VBA it is a function and there should be a return value. If you do not provide a variable for it you get an error. If you simply write MsgBox("myPrompt"), the interpreter assumes "vbOKOnly" (default) and treats this as a method. It's wrong to do even if it is "tolerated".

Comment: Great question.  Never noticed that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a very high level it has to do with how the compiler interprets the commands.

As you noted, both of these work:

```
MsgBox "Hello World"
MsgBox ("Hello World")
```

But this will not (without assigning to a variable):

```
MsgBox ("Hello World", vbYesNo, "Title")
```

This is because (without the assignment), VB thinks there is a single parameter value of `"Hello World", vbYesNo, "Title"`. Obviously, this is incorrect and you get a friendly error message.

If you were to try this, it will work.

```
MsgBox ("Hello World"), (vbYesNo), ("Title")
```

Because each parameter is provided in its own set of parenthesis.

Syntactically, this is exactly like the `MsgBox ("Hello World")` statement above. You are just specifying each parameter in parenthesis instead of only one.

---

**EDIT**

The `MsgBox ("hello world")` works because it ignores the brackets exactly as it would do with a simple integer assignment, such as `x = (2)`.

Comment: You must be right, I didnt think about it! Just to make it clearer, it works because it's ignoring the brackets just as it ignores the brackets with x = (2)?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - Exactly. I'm not sure what the rationale behind `Sub` call parameters not being inside parenthesis is, but "it is what it is".

Comment: Alright, that's clear. If you don't mind, I'll add this small example to your answer to make it 100% complete, even if to me it's already clear (so accepted).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - Great addition. I think that will add clarity to it.